# Is there a systematic way to find the matrices and functions of irreducible representations?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I have been struggling with this question for some time now. Assume you have the multiplication table and the character table of an arbitrary group. Is there a systematic way to find the matrices of the irreps and (some of) the functions that belong to these irreps?

The best I could come up is to form the regular representation and try to reduce that since it contains every irrep but this is getting really difficult really fast. For example, for the full symmetry group of the cube the regular representation is a 48 by 48 matrix. This is too big to reduce without sophisticated software. Any ideas?

Comment: Why using software is not ok? After all it does exist for a reason.

Comment: As a last resort, software is ok. But since I'm really interested in learning, I am looking for an intuitive method, if one exists.

Comment: I don't think there is general method. You just have to use whatever tools you can find. For example in case of symmetry groups the geometry is a handy tool. If some smaller and simpler normal group is present that will give you some representations. Then you can try tensoring the known ones. There is also induction and probably more things. Working with regular representation is not a good idea even for smaller groups. It only works for very small groups such as S_6. Even there it is better to work with transformations than matrices.